# How to flag an id column based on whether it exists in several other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, union

I have 4 tables named as such: france, canada, cameroon, gabon
with each table having a column with ids.

For example France:

```
+------+
|  id  |
+------+
| 1234 |
| 5678 |
| 9213 |
| 4123 |
+------+
```

I need to know which Ids in France doesn't appear in any other table and I need the same for Canada's Ids.

How can I achieve this in one query. I saw that mysql doesn't have full joins or pivot functions so i'm quite clueless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `not exists`. To bring `france` rows that do not exist in any of the 3 other tables:

```
select id
from france f
where not exists (select 1 canada c   where c.id = f.id)
  and not exists (select 1 cameroon c where c.id = f.id)
  and not exists (select 1 gabon g    where g.id = f.id)
```

If you want to search all tables at once for `id`s that do not exists in any other, a more generic approach uses `union all` and aggregation:

```
select id, min(who) who
from (
    select 'france' who, id from france
    union all select 'canada', id from canada
    union all select 'cameroon', id from cameroon
    union all select 'gabon', id from gabon
) t
group by id
having count(*) = 1
```

If a single table may contain duplicate id, you can change the `having` clause to:

```
having min(who) = max(who)
```

Comment: if I want those of canada do , I can just replicate that code and union all with with that of france ?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg: see my updated answer for a more generic approach.